# addInStockFilterToCollection() is not correctly filtering configurable products which are out of stock

Tags: magento-enterprise, stock, magento-1.14

Magento Enterprise 1.14.2.

*Notice: This question is directly related to my other question: [Why does $product->getData["is_in_stock"] differ from $product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183203/why-does-product-getdatais-in-stock-differ-from-product-getstockitem)*

I'm trying to get a collection of all products on my site which are actually in stock:

```
$inStockProducts = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")
                   ->getCollection()
                   ->addAttributeToFilter("status", 1)
                   ->addAttributeToSelect("id");

Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')
      ->addInStockFilterToCollection($inStockProducts);
```

However, the above collection still includes configurable products whose children are all out of stock, and whose *stockItem* stock status is *0* (i.e. out of stock).

It seems like this method is filtering on some kind of inaccurate indexed stock status and not the actual stock item stock status.

For example, I might get the following output from the above code:

```
foreach ($inStockProducts as $inStockProduct) {

    // This might output "0" even though I used the above "InStockFilter"!
    echo $inStockProduct->getStockItem()->getIsInStock();

    // And for the same product this might output "1"!
    echo $inStockProduct->getData["is_in_stock"];

}
```

Reindexing the stock status index (or all indexes) does not have an effect.